# Alterar valor da coluna FALSE TRUE

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho um banco PostgreSQL e preciso alterar a tabela `Produto` com a coluna `Permite_venda`. Os itens estão com `FALSE` e preciso passar para `TRUE`

Como devo fazer?

Eu listo todos abaixo:

```sql
select * from produto where permite_venda = 'f';
```

E como faço o update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prezado,

A sintaxe é **UPDATE** [tabela] **SET** [campo] = [valor] **WHERE** = [criterios];

Abaixo como ficaria (considerando que o 'boolean' que você diz é o valor 't')

```sql
    update produto set permite_venda = 't' where permite_venda = 'f';
```

Comment: Muito obrigado resolveu meu problema

Comment: Disponha, estamos aqui para ajudar. A propósito, peço que marque a resposta como aceita. Abraço.

Comment: Marcos me de outra ajuda

vou fazer um .bat

Montei aqui mas não deu certo 
consegue ver o que fiz de errado

C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin

set PGUSER=postgres
set PGPASSWORD=a011
set PGHOST=localhost
set PGDATABASE=autosystem

update produto set permite_venda = 't' where permite_venda = 'f';

Comment: Nesse caso, tenta abir outra pergunta. Já adianto que nunca fiz esse tipo de procedimento, mas vale uma tentativa, só que por aqui, não conseguimos colocar o código de maneira adequada.

Comment: Tranquilo... Obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score -1):

Basta seguir esse esquema:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1,
    column2 = value2,
    ...
WHERE condition;
```

No seu caso:

```
Update Produto SET Permite_venda = 'true' WHERE id = <id do produto>
```